# Saving command output to variable is not working

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'd like to create simple script to show wlan password on Windows10.
This will be well solution for users that's not familiar with cmd commands.

On Windows 7 it could be done using GUI, but not on newer OSes.

I stuck on line

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%j in ('netsh wlan show profile %ssid% key=clear ^| findstr "Key Content"') do set wlan_password=%%j
```

The variable `wlan_password` is always null. Even if i change `set` instruction to e.g. `echo` it shows that syntax is incorrect. I can't troubleshoot that.

Why the line above doesn't work, but the line:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('netsh wlan show interfaces ^| findstr "Profile"') do set wlan_output=%%i
```

works well?

```
@echo off
set wlan_output=
set connected_ssid=
set ssid=
set wlan_password=
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('netsh wlan show interfaces ^| findstr "Profile"') do set wlan_output=%%i
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ("%wlan_output%") do set connected_ssid=%%a
call :TRIM %connected_ssid% connected_ssid
set ssid=%1
if "%ssid%"=="" set /p "ssid=Podaj nazwe sieci [%connected_ssid%]: " || set "ssid=%connected_ssid%"
if not "%ssid%"=="" (
    for /f "tokens=*" %%j in ('netsh wlan show profile %ssid% key=clear ^| findstr "Key Content"') do set wlan_password=%%j

    echo "Haslo do sieci %ssid%: %wlan_password%"
    exit /b
)
else (
    echo "Nie podano nazwy sieci. Nie mozna odczytac hasla"
    exit /b
)
pause

exit /b
:TRIM
SET %2=%1
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: What is the value of `%ssid%` when the non-working line is run? I suspect it might be empty.

Comment: You may wish to escape the **`=`** character too.

Comment: May the `wlan_password` value contain special Batch characters, like `& < > |`? You should always enclose the var and value in quotes: `do set "wlan_password=%%j"`

Comment: I tried to escape the `=` sign, also added double quotes and put ssid explicitly but still no proper output 
`for /f "tokens=*" %%j in ('netsh wlan show profile my_ssid key ^= clear ^| findstr "Key Content"') do set "wlan_password=%%j"`

Comment: Does the key at least show up with a simple `netsh wlan show profile my_ssid key=clear`?

Comment: Why did you escape the **`=`** character with a space character followed by a caret and then include an additional space character before `clear`? Just a single caret, **`^`**, is the standard escape character!

Comment: @Stephan yes it does.
Compo I deleted spaces, but still it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Ugh - sorry for not spotting the real problem sooner: you have also to escape the `=` within the `for` command:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%j in ('netsh wlan show profile %ssid% key^=clear ^| findstr /c:"Key Content"') do set wlan_password=%%j
set wlan_password
```

Note: use `findstr /c:"Key Content"` or `find "Key Content"`, because `findstr "Key Content"` returns each line that contains `Key` OR `Content` (or both). (Not that it would make any difference in this special case, but without `/c:` it will bite you sooner or later)

To get the key only:

```
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%j in ('netsh wlan show profile %ssid% key^=clear ^| find "Key Content"') do set "wlan_password=%%k"
set "wlan_password=%wlan_password:~1%"
echo ---%wlan_password%---
```

Comment: I commented about the `=` issue previously, Krukosz, even posted their `for` loop in a reply comment with it escaped. I then commented that they had unwanted spaces which they also stated they had fixed but stated that there was no proper output. The only other issue, seems to be that in their question code they had used `%ssid%` but for some reason in their comment they used `my_ssid`.

Comment: I used your solution but still it doesn't work. The result is the same - empty string.

Comment: Hm - you *are*  using an English Windows version, right?

Comment: Nope, but even in polish version of Windows the phrases used in `findstr` are in english. E.g. when i call `netsh` output is in english.